# Elegant approach to prove the convergence of this recursive sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems

Suppose

$$S_1=1,S_{n+1}=S_n+\frac1{S_n}-\sqrt 2$$

Prove that $S_n$ converges.

I was hinted to observe $S_{2k+1}$ and $S_{2k+2}$ respectively, so I tried calculating 
$$S_{n+2}-S_n=\frac{(1-\sqrt 2 S_n)^3}{S_n(S_n^2-\sqrt 2 S_n+1)}$$
This is a bit frustrating, since no immediate indication about the sign can be found in the result.

Maybe after sufficient computation (which I haven't given up on yet) things will begin to be clear, but before that, may I ask whether there is any alternative (elegant ones preferred) to this problem?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: A little sneaky, assume it converges, then solve the equation, you get it converging to $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$. Now, use that fact and come up with a more rigorous proof.

Comment: @Shailesh  Of course I know it does converge to $1/ \sqrt 2$. However the key point of this problem is to prove the "assumption". So I guess it won't be of much help.

Comment: consider the function $f(x)=x+\frac1x -\sqrt 2$. When $x\lt 1$, $f$ is decreasing. And for positive $x$, we know that: $x+\frac1x \ge 2$.

Comment: @math110 Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma**: if $1>x>\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$,then
$$f(f(x))>\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$where $f(x)=x+\dfrac{1}{x}-\sqrt{2}$.

Proof: since
$f(x)=x+\dfrac{1}{x}-\sqrt{2}$ is Monotone decreasing function.so
$$f(f(x))>f\left(f\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

since 
$$S_{n+2}=S_{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{S_{n+1}}-\sqrt{2}=S_{n}+\dfrac{1}{S_{n}}-\sqrt{2}
+\dfrac{1}{S_{n}+\dfrac{1}{S_{n}}-\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{2}$$
first we prove $S_{1}>S_{3}>\cdots>S_{2n+1}$.
Let $f(x)=x+\dfrac{1}{x}-\sqrt{2}$,then we have
$$S_{2n+1}=f(f(S_{2n-1}))$$
$$S_{2n+1}-S_{2n-1}=\dfrac{-2\sqrt{2}S^3_{2n-1}+6S^2_{2n-1}-3\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1}+1}{S_{2n-1}(S^2_{2n-1}-\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1}+1)}=\dfrac{(1-\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1})^3}{S_{2n-1}(S^2_{2n-1}-\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1}+1)}$$
use **Lemma**. we can use induction prove
$$S_{2n+1}>\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},n\ge 1$$
so
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<\cdots<S_{2n+1}<S_{2n-1}<\cdots<S_{3}<S_{1}$$
so
$$\{S_{2n+1}\}$$converges.and we easy to 
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}S_{2k+1}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
the same  as $S_{2}<S_{4}<\cdots<S_{2n}<\cdots<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
so
$$\{S_{2n}\}$$ converges.and
$$\lim_{k\to+\infty}S_{2k}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Add some calculation

\begin{align*}S_{2n+1}-S_{2n-1}&=\dfrac{1}{S_{2n-1}}-2\sqrt{2}+\dfrac{1}{s_{2n-1}+\dfrac{1}{S_{2n-1}}-\sqrt{2}}\\
&=\dfrac{1-2\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1}}{S_{2n-1}}+\dfrac{S_{2n-1}}{S^2_{2n-1}-\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1}+1}\\
&=\dfrac{(1-2\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1})(S^2_{2n-1}-\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1}+1)+S^2_{2n-1}}{S_{2n-1}(S^2_{2n-1}-\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1}+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{S^2_{2n-1}-\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1}+1-2\sqrt{2}S^3_{2n-1}+4S^2_{2n-1}-2\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1}+S^2_{2n-1}}{S_{2n-1}(S^2_{2n-1}-\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1}+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{-2\sqrt{2}S^3_{2n-1}+6S^2_{2n-1}-3\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1}+1}{S_{2n-1}(S^2_{2n-1}-\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1}+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{(1-\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1})^3}{S_{2n-1}(S^2_{2n-1}-\sqrt{2}S_{2n-1}+1)}
\end{align*}

Comment: Do you mean my calculation was wrong?

Comment: yes.$S_{n+2}-S_{n}=\cdots$

Comment: you $S^2_{n}-2\sqrt{2}S_{n}+1$ ,that term$-2\sqrt{2}S_{n}$ is some wrong,because $\dfrac{1}{S_{n}+\dfrac{1}{S_{n}}-\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{S_{n}}{S^2_{n}-\sqrt{2}S_{n}+1}$

Comment: Oops...  I'm sorry.

Comment: I think your second half of the conclusion is wrong. It seems like $S_2\in(0,1/\sqrt 2)$ and $f\circ f(x)<1/\sqrt 2$ on this interval. So $S_{2n+2}-S_{2n}$ is constantly positive.